# Did MySQL 5.7.9 remove support for ALTER IGNORE TABLE?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

Consider the following query:

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE `table_name`
ADD UNIQUE `some_id` (`some_id`);
```

This works fine in MySQL 5.6.25 but in 5.7.9  it gives a syntax error. *Sidenote: Is it just me or was the GA of MysQL 5.7 the most quiet version upgrade ever heard of (or not, as the case may be)?*

Anyways, in 5.7.9 I get the following error:

```
Error in query (1064): Syntax error near 'IGNORE TABLE ... etc
```

I'm hoping it's me mixing up the syntax in which case I'm sorry for wasting your time. In essence: I'm grateful for your help. Thanks.

Comment: I have an explanation on why it was removed here: http://www.tocker.ca/2013/11/06/the-future-of-alter-ignore-table-syntax.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After checking the [**MySQL manual**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html):

> As of MySQL 5.7.4, the IGNORE clause for ALTER TABLE is removed and
>   its use produces an error.

In versions prior to 5.7.4 you get a warning if you use it. Something like:

> 1 warning(s): 1681 'IGNORE' is deprecated and will be removed in a
>   future release.

Comment: I'm checking the link and at the very top it says ALTER [IGNORE] TABLE tbl_name ... so, where exactly does it say so and what do they propose one does instead? Thanks still, but I can't give you a green checkmark yet since that page you linked to is just a joke.

Comment: @Adergaard Check **Usage Notes**

Comment: Marvellous. I'm not being ironic. However, I still think that page sucks as a "find" on it for "alter ignore table" gives zero result and eying through it is a recipe for headache. So, sorting out duplicates for index creation is now a manual job. OK. Thanks, you get the green check mark in 5 minutes when it is allowed to accept answer.

Comment: @Adergaard I would guess it's because which duplicate key is used and which are deleted is unpredictable. The truncate behavior is also very shady. Yes, figuring out what to do with duplicates is a human's job; you don't want your data storage engine *guessing* what data should be silently deleted or silently truncated. "*If IGNORE is specified, only one row is used of rows with duplicates on a unique key. The other conflicting rows are deleted. Incorrect values are truncated to the closest matching acceptable value.*"

Comment: @Schwern you are indeed correct:  http://www.tocker.ca/2013/11/06/the-future-of-alter-ignore-table-syntax.html